# How do you reset or refresh the Zend_Registry?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I had a Zend Web Application which sets it's own basepath and config variables with:

```
Zend_Registry::set()
```

and retrieves via:

```
Zend_Registry::set()
```

However I copied the App to a different location, still using the same database. I then changed the values in the database that were used to set the Zend_registry...
Note: I am using the same Zend_Library (that shouldn't matter though)...

The problem is that when I go to the site it still redirects to the old web app address.

So is there a way of refreshing or resetting the Zend_registry? or does it refresh automatically and that is not the problem?

Comment: It should refresh automatically, not a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not a problem, but
if have such need try this Zend_Registry::_unsetInstance()

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Registry` is based on variables in the local memory, so there's no need to reset it. every hit to the web server initiate a new instance of `Zend_Registry`.